# decrypt a file in nodejs with stdin and stdout

Tags: node.js, encryption

As a exercise of nodeschool I have to decrypt a file by using stdin and stdout.

So I made this :

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var stream = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', process.argv[2]);
var step1 = process.stdin.update(stream);
var step2 = stream.final();
console.log(step2)
//step2.pipe(process.stdout.toString());
```

but now I see this message : TypeError: Not a string or buffer

How to solve this the good way ?

Answer (score 1):

`process.stdin` and `process.stdout` are streams as well as the object created by `crypto.createDecipher()`. You can just chain streams together with calls to `.pipe()` and you're done.

A solution to the problem you are tackling might look like this:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', process.argv[2]);
process.stdin.pipe(decipher).pipe(process.stdout);
```